# How to have .scan() only aggregate the most recent emitted array in an uncompleted sequence

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactive-programming, rxjs, rxjs5

I need to transform and aggregate the elements in an observable array. the sequence is open and will likely never complete (network based).

I am currently using the following code:

```
const numbers = [1,2,3];
const numbers$ = new Rx.Subject();

const output = numbers$
  .flatMap(n => n)
  .map(n => n*n)
  .scan((acc, x) => acc.concat([x]), [])
  .subscribe(n => { console.log(n); });

numbers$.next(numbers);

setTimeout(() => {
  numbers$.next([5,6,7])
}, 1000);
```

Currently, multiple arrays are emitted and the last emitted value currently is `[1, 4, 9, 25, 36, 49]`. However, I only want those values to be squared that are **within the same input array**.

I.e. I need the output observable to emit exactly two arrays: `[1,4,9]` and `[25, 36, 49]`.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
const output = numbers$
    .map((a) => a.map(n => n * n))
    .subscribe(n => { console.log(n); });
```

**Edit:** If you don't want to use `Array.map`, you can use RxJS, instead.

You could replace `Array.map` with an observable that squares the values and reduces them back to an array. This could be extended to include `distinct` or other RxJS operators (as per your comment):

```
const output = numbers$
    .mergeMap(
        (a) => Rx.Observable.from(a)
            .map((n) => n * n)
            .reduce((acc, n) => { acc.push(n); return acc; }, [])
    )
    .subscribe(n => { console.log(n); });
```

The solution that you solution posted:

```
const output = numbers$
    .flatMap(n => n)
    .map(n => n*n)
    .buffer(numbers$.delay(1))
    .subscribe(n => { console.log(n); });
```

is timing-based and the only reason the arrays are not being merged is because the interval between the first `next` call and the second exceeds one millisecond.

Comment: I don't like using the Array.prototype.map() function and rather stick to RxJS. I.e. more complicated transformations like `.distinct()` could also be done

Comment: Your solution using mergeMap/flatMap with nested .from() is the right way to do it. I also utilize a `.toArray()` instead of a .reduce()/.scan() at the end to pack the values back into an array.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is what you need: [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/gosopivuna/edit?html,js,console)

```
const numbers = [1,2,3];
const numbers$ = new Rx.Subject();

const output = numbers$
  .map(numbers => numbers.map(n => n * n))
  .scan((acc, x) => acc.concat([x]), [])
  .subscribe(n => { console.log(n); });

numbers$.next(numbers);

setTimeout(() => {
  numbers$.next([5,6,7])
}, 1000);
```